# How to Unit Test MVVM with Koin?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mvvm, koin

How to Unit Test MVVM with Koin ?

i've try to testing : [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/unlock-your-android-viewmodel-power-with-koin-23eda8f493be)

But, i don't know why i get `error("No Data in ViewModel")` in ViewModelTest `fun getLookUpLeagueList()`

Repository

```
class LookUpLeagueRepository {

    fun getLookUpLeague(idLeague: String): MutableLiveData<LookUpLeague> {
        val lookUpLeague = MutableLiveData<LookUpLeague>()
        APIService().getLookUpLeague(idLeague).enqueue(object : Callback<LookUpLeague> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LookUpLeague>, t: Throwable) {
                d("TAG", "lookUpLeagueOnFailure ${t.localizedMessage}")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<LookUpLeague>, response: Response<LookUpLeague>) {
                lookUpLeague.value = response.body()
            }
        })
        return lookUpLeague
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class LookUpLeagueViewModel(private val lookUpLeagueRepository: LookUpLeagueRepository) :
    ViewModel() {

    var lookUpLeagueList = MutableLiveData<LookUpLeague>()

    fun getLookUpLeagueList(idLeague: String) {
        lookUpLeagueList = lookUpLeagueRepository.getLookUpLeague(idLeague)
    }
}
```

Module

```
val lookUpLeagueModule = module {
    single { LookUpLeagueRepository() }
    viewModel { LookUpLeagueViewModel(get()) }
}
```

ViewModel Test

```
class LookUpLeagueViewModelTest : KoinTest {

    val lookUpLeagueViewModel: LookUpLeagueViewModel by inject()

    val idLeague = "4328"

    @get:Rule
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Mock
    lateinit var observerData: Observer<LookUpLeague>

    @Before
    fun before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        startKoin {
            modules(lookUpLeagueModule)
        }
    }

    @After
    fun after() {
        stopKoin()
    }

    @Test
    fun getLookUpLeagueList() {
        lookUpLeagueViewModel.lookUpLeagueList.observeForever(observerData)

        lookUpLeagueViewModel.getLookUpLeagueList(idLeague)

        val value = lookUpLeagueViewModel.lookUpLeagueList.value ?: error("No Data in ViewModel")

        Mockito.verify(observerData).onChanged(value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Test
fun getLookUpLeagueList() {
    lookUpLeagueViewModel.lookUpLeagueList.observeForever(observerData)
    ...
}
```

At this time `lookUpLeagueList` is an instance of `MutableLiveData`. Say this is `MutableLiveData #1`.

```
lookUpLeagueViewModel.getLookUpLeagueList(idLeague)
```

Executing the line above would call `LookUpLeagueViewModel.getLookUpLeagueList` function. Let's take a look inside it.

```
lookUpLeagueList = lookUpLeagueRepository.getLookUpLeague(idLeague)
```

A totally new `MutableLiveData` is created inside `LookUpLeagueRepository`. That is not the same one as the one `observerData` is observing. At this time `lookUpLeagueViewModel.lookUpLeagueList` refers to the new one, `MutableLiveData #2` because you re-assigned it to `var lookUpLeagueList`.

```
val value = lookUpLeagueViewModel.lookUpLeagueList.value ?: error("No Data in ViewModel")
```

Therefore, you're actually querying against `MutableLiveData #2` which is new, not observed, and empty. That's why `value` is `null`. Instead of declaring as `var`, you should make it `val`. Don't re-assign the variable, `setValue` or `postValue` to propagate the change.

Comment: sorry sir, i get new issue :
1. i try https://gist.github.com/afdaldev/0c3a26664ba00f90a627167546d5ecce , ViewModelTest look good. but i get Empty list in Fragment. And i try https://gist.github.com/afdaldev/7bc9165a899d1398448238bb299ca87d , ViewModelTest get observerData.onChange(null)

Comment: @AfdalDev The first one's issue: `Repository.getLookUpLeague` will return value before async network call completes. The second one's issue: reading value(line 31 of `Test.kt`) will happen before async network call completes.